# react native getting rid of an unnecessary method on store

Tags: function, react-native

Im setting my store on my react native app, is working fine with redux-dev-tools,
but I dont know how to refactor.

```
const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */ 
composeEnhancers(
applyMiddleware(...middleware)));


const configureStore = () => {
return store;
};

export { configureStore };
```

The goal is to export only "store" as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to export `store` as a function as you could just as well export it as an object?

```
export const store = configureStore();
```

This way you could also just import it in any file you like:

```js
import { store } from '...';

// Now you can access the redux store and dispatch actions: 
store.getState() ...
store.dispatch(...)
```